# How to call parameters from one method to another?

Tags: c#, parameters

I have got one method in class

```
public JObject InvokeMethod(string a_sMethod, params object[] a_params)
```

And I need to call this method in bool Test() in another class

```
protected override bool Test ()
{
logger.Write("Test1");
WebServer ws = new WebServer();
ws.InvokeMethod();
}
```

I need to call these two params: a_sMethod and a_params in other class.
Have anyone some idea how to do that ?

```
public string a_sMethod{get; set;}
```

does not work in this case. I get an error: There is no argument that correspondsto the required formal parameter 'a_sMethod' .

Comment: provide more information on what you are trying to do. You probably mean to do "InvokeMethod("Test", null);

Comment: Grab a copy of `C# In Depth` or find some basic programming tutorials. Passing parameters to methods should come somewhere towards the beginning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I get an error: There is no argument that correspondsto the required
>   formal parameter 'a_sMethod' .

error occurs here because you haven't specified the correct arguments for the method.

```
 ws.InvokeMethod();
```

The method signature below expects a string and any number of data to be passed in:

```
public JObject InvokeMethod(string a_sMethod, params object[] a_params)
```

Example:

```
ws.InvokeMethod("testing", 1,2,3,4,5,5); // this is just for illustration, you can pass in the data you want to work with.
```

There are disadvantages of using `object` type as `params array` but it's beyond the scope of this question, so I will let that pass.

**UPDATE**

if you want to use properties, that's also simple.All you have to do is just set the data for that particular property and pass them in as the `InvokeMethod(string a_sMethod, params object[] a_params)` method parameters expect.

Comment: OK, Thank You for quick feedback. I will try with this solution. I have one more question what about simple string parameteres in bool method, when I want to call in other class and bool method ?

Comment: Same process but this time around you need to pass in 1 parameter of type string and store the returned value somewhere. Also if my post has helped I would really appreciate it if you mark it as accepted. Thanks.